# Skype MSI installation fails

Tags: installation, skype

I'm trying to install skype_6.0.0.120.msi to my Windows xp (32 bit) laptop.

But if I double click the setup, it shows the message like

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package".

Why?

Comment: Not duplicate sorry, looked confusingly the same at first glance.

Comment: download the MSI again.

Comment: Yeap.. I have downloaded again which is not corrupted...

Comment: sathya: I try to download MSI again.. Can you give me a worthy link?

Comment: where did you download it fro,?

Comment: Sathya Now, I have downloaded from microsoft link. Still, having same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to a corrupted file.

Try downloading the software from either

- [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_skype/) or
- [Skype.com](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/windows/)

Comment: The OP said they tried downloading again and the file wasn't corrupted.

Comment: I have downloaded skype setup from www.skype.com Same problem occur again..

Comment: try it from filehippo.com

Comment: Please don't! See my comment above. Get the official version from the official site only. If having problems with downloaded files, try a different browser first.

Answer (score 3):

You have a corrupted file. There are a couple of possibilities.

Firstly, check that you are actually downloading from Microsoft not from another site.

Secondly, try another browser to do the download, it can happen that browsers mangle the downloads. Also try forcing a refresh of the cache by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> to do a full reload of the download page.

The official place to download Skype is from http://www.skype.com
Don't download from anywhere else.

Comment: "Firstly, check that you are actually downloading from Microsoft not from another site"? Merger in progress?

Comment: I have downloaded skype setup from www.skype.com and windows installer from microsoft link.

Comment: I installed skype_5.9.0.115.260.msi successfully.. :)

Comment: @TFM: Skype is now owned by Microsoft and has been for a while. If you see the news, Microsoft are replacing their own instant messaging tool with Skype.

Comment: @JulianKnight: You are right. To be clear, I was confused by your two different statements on where to download to software. "Check that you are actually downloading from Microsoft not from another site" opposed to "The official place to download Skype is from http://www.skype.com Don't download from anywhere else."